# Bind-mount a host directory into a volume of a running docker container

Tags: docker, storage, volume

Let's say that I start a docker container with a bind-mounted local folder:

```
docker run --rm -v /ux1/dmtest:/data -it ubuntu
```

Then, locally - not inside the container, I bind-mount a directory from another fs into `/ux1/dmtest`:

```
mkdir /ux1/dmtest/bm
mount --bind /ux0/bm /ux1/dmtest/bm
```

Now, from the container, I see `/data/bm/` and I can write content to it, but this content will not be visible on the host on `/ux0/bm`.

Where is this content stored?
And is there any way to mount additional storage into a running docker container (this workaround clearly doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounts done after the fact won't be seen by the container due to mount namespaces that Docker uses. The files will be in the /ux1/dmtest directory that was in place before your second bind mount.

If you do want to use a bind mount, put it in place, and then start the docker daemon, and then your container will see it.